# Почему popup не в центре, а внизу?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Popup должен появляться посередине. Подключил библиотеку Animate.js. До анимации всё работало хорошо и popup появлялся в центре. Как только добавил анимацию, он съехал вниз... Если менять свойства top и left popup смещается. Но я не пойму, как поставить его по центру, если мой код для центровки перестаёт работать из-за анимации.

```js
$('.open-popup').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.popup-bg').fadeIn(400);
    $('html').addClass('no-scroll');
});
```

```css
.popup{
    position: absolute;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 50%;
    height: 70%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 30px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 4px solid #4BB512;

}
.popup-bg{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    z-index: 200;
    display: none;
}


.no-scroll{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="menu" id="menu">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="home.html">ADVISE2.0</a>    
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">История</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Спорт</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Наука</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Люди</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="btn2 open-popup"><a href="#">Добавить Эдвайс</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="popup-bg">
                <div class="popup animate__animated animate__bounceInLeft">
                    hdhdhdhdhhdhd
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="plot">
                <div class="appeal">Вдохновись опытом других!</div>
                <div class="posting"><!-- весь помт целиком, включая авторов и кто постит и фото-->
                    <div class="whopost"> <!-- линия, кто сделал пост -->
                        @Amin
                    </div>
                    <div class="quoteline"> <!-- линия, включающая в себя прямоугольник с цитатой и фотку гворящего -->
                        <div class="rect"> <!-- прямоуг с цитатой -->
                            <div class="quotetext">
                                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit”
                            </div>
                            <div class="quotespeaker">
                                -Amin Kipkeev

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="photo"><!-- кто говорил фотка -->
                            <img src="icons/user.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="posting"><!-- весь помт целиком, включая авторов и кто постит и фото-->
                    <div class="whopost"> <!-- линия, кто сделал пост -->
                        @Amin
                    </div>
                    <div class="quoteline"> <!-- линия, включающая в себя прямоугольник с цитатой и фотку гворящего -->
                        <div class="rect"> <!-- прямоуг с цитатой -->
                            <div class="quotetext">
                                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit”
                            </div>
                            <div class="quotespeaker">
                                -Amin Kipkeev

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="photo"><!-- кто говорил фотка -->
                            <img src="icons/user.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="posting"><!-- весь помт целиком, включая авторов и кто постит и фото-->
                    <div class="whopost"> <!-- линия, кто сделал пост -->
                        @Amin
                    </div>
                    <div class="quoteline"> <!-- линия, включающая в себя прямоугольник с цитатой и фотку гворящего -->
                        <div class="rect"> <!-- прямоуг с цитатой -->
                            <div class="quotetext">
                                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit”
                            </div>
                            <div class="quotespeaker">
                                -Amin Kipkeev

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="photo"><!-- кто говорил фотка -->
                            <img src="icons/user.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="posting"><!-- весь помт целиком, включая авторов и кто постит и фото-->
                    <div class="whopost"> <!-- линия, кто сделал пост -->
                        @Amin
                    </div>
                    <div class="quoteline"> <!-- линия, включающая в себя прямоугольник с цитатой и фотку гворящего -->
                        <div class="rect"> <!-- прямоуг с цитатой -->
                            <div class="quotetext">
                                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit”
                            </div>
                            <div class="quotespeaker">
                                -Amin Kipkeev

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="photo"><!-- кто говорил фотка -->
                            <img src="icons/user.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="posting"><!-- весь помт целиком, включая авторов и кто постит и фото-->
                    <div class="whopost"> <!-- линия, кто сделал пост -->
                        @Amin
                    </div>
                    <div class="quoteline"> <!-- линия, включающая в себя прямоугольник с цитатой и фотку гворящего -->
                        <div class="rect"> <!-- прямоуг с цитатой -->
                            <div class="quotetext">
                                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit”
                            </div>
                            <div class="quotespeaker">
                                -Amin Kipkeev

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="photo"><!-- кто говорил фотка -->
                            <img src="icons/user.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: При запуске кода всё происходит отлично, popup посередине

Comment: Можете попробовать вместо top, bottom, right, left использовать `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;` или `display: grid; place-content: center;`

Comment: @ИванИпатов Поменял в коде вопроса путь к animate.css на [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/animate.css), и проблема тут же образовалась

Answer (score 1):

Вы центируете с помощьсю свойства `transform`, а анимация использует его же.

Надо либо менять анимацию, либо менять способ центровки.

Поскольку размеры попапа заданы в процентах, почему бы тогда не рассчитать оставшиеся проценты и не задать их в `top` и `left`?

А чтобы `padding` не портил расчёты, добавить `box-sizing: border-box;`.

```js
$('.open-popup').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.popup-bg').fadeIn(400);
    $('html').addClass('no-scroll');
});
```

```css
body * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup{
    position: absolute;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 50%;
    height: 70%;
    left: 25%;  /* = (100% - 50% width)  / 2 */
    top:  15%;  /* = (100% - 70% height) / 2 */ 
    /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
    padding: 30px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 4px solid #4BB512;
}

.popup-bg{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    z-index: 200;
    display: none;
}

.no-scroll{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="menu" id="menu">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="home.html">ADVISE2.0</a>    
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">История</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Спорт</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Наука</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Люди</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="btn2 open-popup"><a href="#">Добавить Эдвайс</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="popup-bg">
                <div class="popup animate__animated animate__bounceInLeft">
                    hdhdhdhdhhdhd
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="plot">
                <div class="appeal">Вдохновись опытом других!</div>
                <div class="posting"><!-- весь помт целиком, включая авторов и кто постит и фото-->
                    <div class="whopost"> <!-- линия, кто сделал пост -->
                        @Amin
                    </div>
                    <div class="quoteline"> <!-- линия, включающая в себя прямоугольник с цитатой и фотку гворящего -->
                        <div class="rect"> <!-- прямоуг с цитатой -->
                            <div class="quotetext">
                                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit”
                            </div>
                            <div class="quotespeaker">
                                -Amin Kipkeev

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="photo"><!-- кто говорил фотка -->
                            <img src="icons/user.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="posting"><!-- весь помт целиком, включая авторов и кто постит и фото-->
                    <div class="whopost"> <!-- линия, кто сделал пост -->
                        @Amin
                    </div>
                    <div class="quoteline"> <!-- линия, включающая в себя прямоугольник с цитатой и фотку гворящего -->
                        <div class="rect"> <!-- прямоуг с цитатой -->
                            <div class="quotetext">
                                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit”
                            </div>
                            <div class="quotespeaker">
                                -Amin Kipkeev

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="photo"><!-- кто говорил фотка -->
                            <img src="icons/user.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="posting"><!-- весь помт целиком, включая авторов и кто постит и фото-->
                    <div class="whopost"> <!-- линия, кто сделал пост -->
                        @Amin
                    </div>
                    <div class="quoteline"> <!-- линия, включающая в себя прямоугольник с цитатой и фотку гворящего -->
                        <div class="rect"> <!-- прямоуг с цитатой -->
                            <div class="quotetext">
                                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit”
                            </div>
                            <div class="quotespeaker">
                                -Amin Kipkeev

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="photo"><!-- кто говорил фотка -->
                            <img src="icons/user.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="posting"><!-- весь помт целиком, включая авторов и кто постит и фото-->
                    <div class="whopost"> <!-- линия, кто сделал пост -->
                        @Amin
                    </div>
                    <div class="quoteline"> <!-- линия, включающая в себя прямоугольник с цитатой и фотку гворящего -->
                        <div class="rect"> <!-- прямоуг с цитатой -->
                            <div class="quotetext">
                                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit”
                            </div>
                            <div class="quotespeaker">
                                -Amin Kipkeev

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="photo"><!-- кто говорил фотка -->
                            <img src="icons/user.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="posting"><!-- весь помт целиком, включая авторов и кто постит и фото-->
                    <div class="whopost"> <!-- линия, кто сделал пост -->
                        @Amin
                    </div>
                    <div class="quoteline"> <!-- линия, включающая в себя прямоугольник с цитатой и фотку гворящего -->
                        <div class="rect"> <!-- прямоуг с цитатой -->
                            <div class="quotetext">
                                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit”
                            </div>
                            <div class="quotespeaker">
                                -Amin Kipkeev

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="photo"><!-- кто говорил фотка -->
                            <img src="icons/user.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Немного отредактировал ваш CSS:

```js
$('.open-popup').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.popup-bg').fadeIn(400);
    $('html').addClass('no-scroll');
});
```

```css
.popup {
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  padding: 30px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 4px solid #4bb512;
}
.popup-bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  z-index: 200;
  display: none;
}
.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.popup__wrapper {
  display: flex;,
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="menu" id="menu">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="home.html">ADVISE2.0</a>    
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">История</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Спорт</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Наука</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Люди</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="btn2 open-popup"><a href="#">Добавить Эдвайс</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="popup-bg">
              <div class="popup__wrapper">
                <div class="popup animate__animated animate__bounceInLeft">
                    hdhdhdhdhhdhd
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>              
            <div class="plot">
                <div class="appeal">Вдохновись опытом других!</div>
                <div class="posting"><!-- весь помт целиком, включая авторов и кто постит и фото-->
                    <div class="whopost"> <!-- линия, кто сделал пост -->
                        @Amin
                    </div>
                    <div class="quoteline"> <!-- линия, включающая в себя прямоугольник с цитатой и фотку гворящего -->
                        <div class="rect"> <!-- прямоуг с цитатой -->
                            <div class="quotetext">
                                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit”
                            </div>
                            <div class="quotespeaker">
                                -Amin Kipkeev

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="photo"><!-- кто говорил фотка -->
                            <img src="icons/user.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="posting"><!-- весь помт целиком, включая авторов и кто постит и фото-->
                    <div class="whopost"> <!-- линия, кто сделал пост -->
                        @Amin
                    </div>
                    <div class="quoteline"> <!-- линия, включающая в себя прямоугольник с цитатой и фотку гворящего -->
                        <div class="rect"> <!-- прямоуг с цитатой -->
                            <div class="quotetext">
                                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit”
                            </div>
                            <div class="quotespeaker">
                                -Amin Kipkeev

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="photo"><!-- кто говорил фотка -->
                            <img src="icons/user.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="posting"><!-- весь помт целиком, включая авторов и кто постит и фото-->
                    <div class="whopost"> <!-- линия, кто сделал пост -->
                        @Amin
                    </div>
                    <div class="quoteline"> <!-- линия, включающая в себя прямоугольник с цитатой и фотку гворящего -->
                        <div class="rect"> <!-- прямоуг с цитатой -->
                            <div class="quotetext">
                                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit”
                            </div>
                            <div class="quotespeaker">
                                -Amin Kipkeev

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="photo"><!-- кто говорил фотка -->
                            <img src="icons/user.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="posting"><!-- весь помт целиком, включая авторов и кто постит и фото-->
                    <div class="whopost"> <!-- линия, кто сделал пост -->
                        @Amin
                    </div>
                    <div class="quoteline"> <!-- линия, включающая в себя прямоугольник с цитатой и фотку гворящего -->
                        <div class="rect"> <!-- прямоуг с цитатой -->
                            <div class="quotetext">
                                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit”
                            </div>
                            <div class="quotespeaker">
                                -Amin Kipkeev

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="photo"><!-- кто говорил фотка -->
                            <img src="icons/user.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="posting"><!-- весь помт целиком, включая авторов и кто постит и фото-->
                    <div class="whopost"> <!-- линия, кто сделал пост -->
                        @Amin
                    </div>
                    <div class="quoteline"> <!-- линия, включающая в себя прямоугольник с цитатой и фотку гворящего -->
                        <div class="rect"> <!-- прямоуг с цитатой -->
                            <div class="quotetext">
                                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit”
                            </div>
                            <div class="quotespeaker">
                                -Amin Kipkeev

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="photo"><!-- кто говорил фотка -->
                            <img src="icons/user.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

В современной вёрстке, как по мне, стоит использовать такие методы как flex или grid, так как есть адаптивность и проблем меньше. Учтите, я выравнивал дочерний элемент `.popup`, а родительский у него `.popup__wrapper`.
Также в код был добавлен дополнительный элемент `.popup__wrapper` для сохранения стилей `.popup-bg` и оцентровки. Сопутсвующие стили к нему тоже были добавлены.

Comment: Попап сейчас сразу вылетает, не дожидаясь клика по "Добавить"

Comment: @GlebKemarsky проверьте, теперь не должно быть такого, это всё происходило из-за `display: none`, когда нужен был `display: flex`, я добавил `wrapper`, должно быть всё нормально

Comment: Работает, но, кажется, стоит добавить в ответ пояснение насчёт добавленного блока